# Synch on mobile data not only wifi

Tags: wi-fi, mobile-data

It appears my S planner synchs when I am on Wi Fi but not when wi fi is off and I am connected to mobile data.  There is probably a switch "synch only when on wifi" to save paying for mobile data, but where do I turn that off if I want to synch in a hurry and there is no wifi handy?

Comment: Specifying which Samsung model, Android version will help in others give a specific answer